# Initializing the weights of a model from the output of another model in keras for transfer learning

Tags: keras, transfer-learning

I trained a LeNet architecture on a first dataset. I want to train a VGG  architecture on an other dataset by initializing the weights of VGG with weights obtained from LeNet.

All initialization functions in keras are predefined and I do not find how to customize them. For example :

```
keras.initializers.Zeros()
```

Any idea how I can set the weights?

Comment: so you are just trying to set the weights of specific layers of the model in Keras?

Answer (score 0):

https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

According to the Keras documentation above:

- `layer.set_weights(weights)` sets the weights of the layer from a list of Numpy arrays
- `layer.get_weights()` returns the weights of the layer as a list of Numpy arrays

So, you can do this as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32))
... building the model's layers ...

# access any nth layer by calling model.layers[n]
model.layers[0].set_weights( your_weights_here )
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure you are setting the weights of each layer to the appropriate shape they should be.